# Re-try azure SCM deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I have an Azure site connected to my Bitbucket repo for continuous deployment. With Bitbucket being unstable today my deployments are occasionally failing when I commit with the following error:

```
abort: no suitable response from remote hg! 
D:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\hg.exe pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo/ --branch default --noninteractive
```

If I commit then the deployment tries again and fails again. I cannot seem to find a way to get azure to retry the deployment. Rather than fill my commit history with "Trying deployment again" I'd like to be able to get it to retry.

Comment: The Azure docs themselves state in no uncertain terms to push to the repo again to re-trigger the deployment.

Comment: Thanks. Which docs? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/  While the meat of the doc is for git, it also references bitbucket.  The mechanism is essentially the same so the remediation would be the same as well.